# adding certain html variables into a mailer variable using php and if-statement

Tags: php, html, if-statement

While writing my website I encountered the following Problem:
On the first page, you can enter some data like names, dates, addresses etc.
In addition, there are a few checkboxes with fixed data.
After filling out the form I want it to get sent to my e-mail, which is working for the most part.

```
<?php
//subject of the e-mail
$subject = "Test";

// the message
$msg = "Antragssteller: " . $_POST['ANachname'] . ", " . $_POST['AVorname'] . "<br>E-Mail: " . $_POST['AMail'] . "<br><br>" .
    "Testperson: " . $_POST['MNachname'] . ", " . $_POST['MVorname'] . "<br>Adresse: " . $_POST['Adresse'] . "<br><br>";

// use wordwrap() if lines are longer than 70 characters
$msg = wordwrap($msg,70);

// send email
sendMailInt($subject, $msg);
?>
```

Now I want to add some input with checkboxes on my website, which also works up to a certain point.

```
<?php
//subject of the e-mail
$subject = "Test";

// the message
$msg = "Antragssteller: " . $_POST['ANachname'] . ", " . $_POST['AVorname'] . "<br>E-Mail: " . $_POST['AMail'] . "<br><br>" .
    "Testperson: " . $_POST['MNachname'] . ", " . $_POST['MVorname'] . "<br>Adresse: " . $_POST['Adresse'] . "<br><br>" .
    "checkbox1: " . $_POST['checkbox1'] . "<br>" .
    "checkbox2: " . $_POST['checkbox2'] . "<br>" .
    "checkbox3: " . $_POST['checkbox3'] . "<br>" .
    "checkbox4: " . $_POST['checkbox4'] . "<br>" .
    "checkbox5: " . $_POST['checkbox5'] . "<br>" .
    "checkbox6: " . $_POST['checkbox6'] . "<br>" .
    "checkbox7: " . $_POST['checkbox7'] . "<br>" .
    "checkbox8: " . $_POST['checkbox8'] . "<br>" .
    ;

// use wordwrap() if lines are longer than 70 characters
$msg = wordwrap($msg,70);

// send email
sendMailInt($subject, $msg);
?>
```

Specifically for the checkbox input, I want to have something like an if-statement to check if the box has been checked or not.
If a box is unchecked, the value is empty, which means I have an empty line in my e-mail. Since I have around 20 checkboxes, it can get a bit messy in the e-mail, if 10 boxes in a row are unchecked.

I tried writing the `$msg =` as HTML mail and adding PHP code into it, but then my website stopped working (went completely blank, an error I encountered a few times before, when using wrong code)

```
<?php
//subject of the e-mail
$subject = "Test";

// the message
$msg = "
<html>
<head>
<title>Test Mail</title>
<body>
<?php
    echo "Antragssteller: " . $_POST['ANachname'] . ", " . $_POST['AVorname'] . "<br>E-Mail: " . $_POST['AMail'] . "<br><br>" .
    "Testperson: " . $_POST['MNachname'] . ", " . $_POST['MVorname'] . "<br>Adresse: " . $_POST['Adresse'] . "<br><br>"; 
    if ($_POST['checkbox1'] == true)
        echo $_POST['checkbox1'] . "<br>";
    else
        echo "";

    if ($_POST['checkbox2'] == true)
        echo $_POST['checkbox2'] . "<br>";
    else
        echo "";

    if ($_POST['checkbox3'] == true)
        echo $_POST['checkbox3'] . "<br>";
    else
        echo "";

    if ($_POST['checkbox4'] == true)
        echo $_POST['checkbox4'] . "<br>";
    else
        echo "";

    if ($_POST['checkbox5'] == true)
        echo $_POST['checkbox5'] . "<br>";
    else
        echo "";

    if ($_POST['checkbox6'] == true)
        echo $_POST['checkbox6'] . "<br>";
    else
        echo "";

    if ($_POST['checkbox7'] == true)
        echo $_POST['checkbox7'] . "<br>";
    else
        echo "";

    if ($_POST['checkbox8'] == true)
        echo $_POST['checkbox8'] . "<br>";
    else
        echo "";
?>
</body>
</html>
";

// use wordwrap() if lines are longer than 70 characters
$msg = wordwrap($msg,70);

// send email
sendMailInt($subject, $msg);
?>
```

Is there any way to skip empty variables in the mailer variable, so that the mail that gets sent looks clean without holes?

Looking forward to hearing from you guys and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing you can do is in the file you're working with to force errors to show on the page (only use this in development environments):

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Second, multiple form inputs of the same data type can be greatly simplified by putting them in an array. Here's what the syntax would look like:

```
<input name="checkbox[]" value="1" />
<input name="checkbox[]" value="2" />
<input name="checkbox[]" value="3" />
<input name="checkbox[]" value="4" />
<input name="checkbox[]" value="5" />
```

Then in PHP you could do something like this that will only print out the checkboxes that were selected:

```
foreach ($_POST['checkbox'] as $checkbox) {
  echo $checkbox . "<br>";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this helps a lot improving the code for my website. But I am still not sure how i can include this part 
`foreach ($_POST['checkbox'] as $checkbox) {
  echo $checkbox . "<br>";
}`
into my `$msg` variable that contains the complete text for my e-mail

Comment: Edit:
i also added the error reporting code to my script, but the website is still blank when using the `foreach` part inside the `$msg` variable

Comment: You can instead give each checkbox a specific name like so:
`<input name="checkbox[1]" value="1" />`
From there you can run a `for()` loop that goes from 1-8 that sets the message for each line (i.e. checkbox1, checkbox2, etc.) and have an if statement in there that adds the checkbox data to the line if matches the index of `$_POST['checkbox']`

Comment: after trying around and modifying the code you provided i realised the following:
i tried adding the `foreach` statement directly into the `$msg` variable, which of course did not work.
Instead i now rewrote it to
`foreach ($_POST['checkbox'] as $checkbox) 
 {
  $msg .= $checkbox . "<br>" ;
 }`
and added it to my code seperately from the `$msg` variable.
Now it is adding the checked checkboxvalues correctly to my e-mail.
The code looks like this:
`$msg = "Antragssteller: " . $_POST['Name'] . "<br>"; 
foreach ($_POST['checkbox'] as $checkbox) 
 {
  $msg .= $checkbox . "<br>" ;
 }`

Comment: Very awesome! Let me know if there's anything else you run into.